# How to take care of moving mean and moving variance using tf.nn.batch_normalization?

Tags: python, tensorflow, batch-normalization

Somehow for my implementation, I have to define the weights first and can not use high level functions in tensorflow like tf.layers.batch_normalization or tf.layers.dense. So to do batch normalization I need to use tf.nn.batch_normalization. I know that for calculating mean and variance of each minibatch I can use tf.nn.moments, but what about moving mean and variance? Does anyone have experience with doing that or knows an example of implementation? I see that people talk about using tf.nn.batch_normalization could be tricky so I want to know the complexity of doing that. In other words, what makes it tricky and what points I should be careful about during my implementation? Is there any other point besides moving average and variance that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 3):

You have to be wary of the terms `running_mean` and `running_variance`. In mathematics and in traditional cocmputer science, they are referred to as methods which compute these values without having seen the complete data. They are also known as `online` versions of `mean` and `variance`. Not that they are able to accurately determine the `mean` and `variance` beforehand. They simply keep on updaing the value of some variables `mean` and `variance`, as more data comes in. If your data size is finite, then once having seen the complete data, their values would match the values one would compute, if the complete data is made available.

The case of batch normalization is different. You should not think of `running mean` and `running variance` in the same way as in the above paragraph.

**Training Time**

During training, the `mean` and `variance` are computed for a `batch`. They is not `running mean` or `running variance`. So, you can safely use `tf.nn.moments` to do that.

**Testing Time**

During testing time, you use what should be called as `population_estimated_mean` and `population_estimated_variance`. These quantities are computed during training but are not directly used. They are computed for later use during testing time.

Now one pitfall is that, some people might want to use the `Knuth Formula` for computing these quantities. This is not advisable. **Why? :** Because, training is done over several `epochs`. So, the same dataset is seen for as many times as the number of `epochs`. Since data augmentation is also usually random, computing the standard `running mean` and `running variance`, could be dangerous. Instead what is usually used is an `exponentially decaying estimate`.

You can achieve this, by using `tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage` over `batch_mean` and `batch_variance`. Here you specify that how much relevance will be given to past samples vis-a-vis present samples. Be sure that the variables you use for computing this should be `non-trainable` by setting `trainable=False`.

During test time, you will use these variables as `mean` and `variance`.

For more details on implementation you can take a look at [this link](https://r2rt.com/implementing-batch-normalization-in-tensorflow.html).